# How to reverse serial data capture C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I get this for Serial Port -  `0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000`
Correct MAC is - `this 88:E9:FE:A8:1F:2F`

I want to know a correct way to organize.

```
        string Data = "0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000";
        rtf.AppendTex(Mac_Reverso(Data));

        public static string Mac_Reverso(string macAddress)
        {
           string macRevertido = string.Empty;
           string s = macAddress.Replace("0x", "");
           string[] macLista = s.Split(' ');

           foreach (var mac in macLista)
           {
            for (var i = mac.Length; i > 0; i -= 2)
             {
                macRevertido += mac.Substring(i - 2, 2);
                if (macRevertido.Length == 12)
                {                       
                    return macRevertido;
                }
              }                               
            }
            return macRevertido; //op 88E9FE9DB3D2
        }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] also this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and also [mcve]

Comment: Also take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=net-5.0

Comment: Isn't the received data purposely converted to 32bit DWORD? Or is it converted to 32bit DWORD before sending? It seems that there is no problem if both transmission and reception are handled as a byte array.

Comment: Hi @kunif I need to show the MAC correctly to the system user. And after he edit send the new mac the same way I get through the serial port

Comment: As @TheGeneral commented, information about the program source and what the unprocessed data looks like right after it is received so that others can investigate, reproduce and verify your problem. Please add. It is difficult to get advice or answers no matter how much abstract sentences without such information are shown.

Comment: @kunif I put my code for invert hex string.

Comment: Isn't `txtMac.Text` the content of the character string that you have already converted to text and displayed? Please add what happened to the byte array data when it was received by reading the serial port, including what method was used to read the data.

Comment: Hi i receveid packet using Serialport.ReadLine();      SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;var data = sp.ReadLine();

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an hacky way but you could do the following:

```
public static string Mac_Reverso(string macAddress)
        {
            string macRevertido = string.Empty;
            string s = macAddress.Replace("0x", "");
            string[] macLista = s.Split(' ');

            foreach (var mac in macLista)
            {
                for (var i = mac.Length; i > 0; i -= 2)
                {
                    macRevertido += mac.Substring(i - 2, 2) + ":";
                    if (macRevertido.Length >= 17)
                    {
                        return macRevertido.Substring(0, macRevertido.Length-1);
                    }
                }
            }
            return macRevertido; //op 88E9FE9DB3D2
        }
```